# Генерация случайных чисел в С: все числа одинаковые

Tags: c, случайные-числа

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("%d",gerRandomInt());
    printf("\n");

    printf("%d",gerRandomInt());
    printf("\n");

    printf("%d",gerRandomInt());
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

int gerRandomInt()
{
    srand(time(NULL));  
    return rand()%1000 + 1; // от 1 до 1000
}
```

Все три числа  каждый раз одинаковые при каждом запуске.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получать каждый раз уникальное число?**

Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Уж сколько раз твердили миру....

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

вызывается в программе **ОДИН РАЗ**.

Каждое следующее псевдослучайное число создается из предыдущего. `srand` и устанавливает это "предыдущее". Результат - вы (в пределах одной секунды) постоянно просите выводить одно и то же число...