# Как узнать максимальное и минимальное значение функции c srand(time(NULL))?

Tags: c++, генерация-случайных-данных

```
int tick() {
srand(time(NULL));
int r{0};
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    r += rand() % 2;
}

return r;
```

}

Comment: О какой именно "функции" идет речь? И что вообще делает `srand(time(NULL))` внутри такой обычной функции, как эта `tick`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значения генерируются в диапазоне `[0 .. RAND_MAX]`. А вообще вместо этой функции следует использовать утилиты из `<random>`, они позволяют гибко задавать поведение.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, функция генерирует случайные числа от 0-100, но часть rand() %2 мне не совсем ясна. 2% это от секунд с полуночи 1970?

Comment: @VTT: Бесполезный? Вообще-то это не так. Распределение такой суммы сильно отличается от распределения `rand() % 101`. Это уже вопрос того, какое распределение хотели получить. (Аналогично: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/820241/Генерация-случайных-дробных-чисел)

Comment: @AnT: при запуске отображается повторяющийся набор чисел от 38 до 63, если не трудно, объясните пожалуйста по какому принципу они формируются.

Comment: @Gabe Mccloud: Не ясно, что вы имеете в виду. "При запуске" эта функция будет генерировать числа от 0 до 100, как уже правильно сказал VTT. Однако сидящий внутри `srand(time(NULL))` - типичная ошибка, которая может привести к "одинаковости" генерируемых значений и исказить результаты. (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828303/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%A1-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5)